# Iterating through a subset of dimensions

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to iterate through a subset of dimensions of a numpy array and compare the resulting array elements (which are arrays or the remaining dimension(s)).

The code below does this:

```
import numpy

def min(h,m):
    return h*60+m

exclude_times_default=[min(3,00),min(6,55)]
d=exclude_times_default
exclude_times_wkend=[min(3,00),min(9,00)]
w=exclude_times_wkend;

exclude_times=numpy.array([[[min(3,00),min(6,20)],d,d,d,d,d,[min(3,00),min(6,20)],d,d,[min(3,00),min(6,20)]],
                           [d,d,d,d,[min(3,00),min(9,30)],[min(3,00),min(9,30)],d,d,d,d],
                           [[min(20,00),min(7,15)],[min(3,00),min(23,15)],[min(3,00),min(7,15)],[min(3,00),min(7,15)],[min(3,00),min(23,15)],[min(3,00),min(23,15)],d,d,d,d]])

num_level=exclude_times.shape[0]
num_wind=exclude_times.shape[1]
for level in range(num_level):
    for window in range(num_wind):
        if (exclude_times[level,window,:]==d).all():
            print("Default")
            exclude_times[level][window]=w
        print(level,window,exclude_times[level][window])
```

The solution does not look very elegant to me, just wondering if there are more elegant solutions.

Comment: Is the printing of "Default" important? Or just seeing default to weekend?

Comment: Do you realize that `exclude_times[level,window,:]` and `exclude_times[level][window]` are the same indexing?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a 2D mask pinpointing all the window/level combinations set to default like this:

```
mask = (exclude_times == d[None, None, :]).all(axis=-1)
```

The expression `d[None, None, :]` introduces two [new axes](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) into a view of `d` to make it [broadcast](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to the shape of `exclude_times` properly. Another way to do that would be with an explicit [`reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html): `np.reshape(d, (1, 1, -1))` or `d.reshape(1, 1, -1)`. There are many other ways as well.

The `.all(axis=-1)` operation reduces the 3D boolean mask along the last axis, giving you a 2D mask indexed be level and window.

To count the number of default entries, use [`np.countnonzero`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzero.html):

```
nnz = np.countnonzero(mask)
```

To count the defaults for each window:

```
np.countnonzero(mask, axis=0)
```

To count the defaults for each level:

```
np.countnonzero(mask, axis=1)
```

Remember, the axis parameter is the one you reduce, not the one(s) you keep.

Assigning `w` to the default elements is a bit more complex. The problem is that `exclude_times[mask[:, :, None]]` is a copy of the original data, and doesn't preserve the shape of the original at all.

You have to do a couple of extra steps to reshape correctly:

```
exclude_times[mask[:, :, None]] = np.broadcast_to(w[None, :], (nnz, 2)).ravel()
```